# Wavefront export with [Vertex/texture-coordinate/normal] face definitions

Tags: export

I downloaded wavefront obj model from this site http://tf3dm.com/3d-model/edward-kenway-23504.html.

The model I downloaded (According to this wikipedia article: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) has "Vertex/texture-coordinate/normal" face definitions. I use blender v2.66 to import and export the model. The problem is when I export the model its face definitions are different. For example:

Before import/export:

```
usemtl EdwardKenwayHead
s 1
f 15420/12835/15421 15421/12836/15422 15422/12837/15423
f 15422/12837/15423 15423/12838/15424 15420/12835/15421
f 15419/12839/15425 15420/12835/15421 15423/12838/15424
f 15423/12838/15424 15422/12837/15423 15424/12840/15426
f 15424/12840/15426 15425/12841/15427 15423/12838/15424
```

After import/export:

```
usemtl EdwardKenwayHead
s 1
f 1/1 2/2 3/3
f 4/4 1/1 3/3
f 5/5 1/1 4/4
f 4/4 3/3 6/6
f 6/6 7/7 4/4
```

Is there any way to export wavefronts with "Vertex/texture-coordinate/normal" face definitions in Blender? (v2.66) I already have C++ & OpenGL loader models with these faces.

By the way. Before export the model's size is 2.8KB and after export it is 1.8KB - good optimalization!

Answer (score 1):

There are several objects included in the one file, all vertices listed are numbered in the order they exist in the file, each object then uses a range of these vertices for it's faces.

You will find that the objects and it's related items in your exported file will be in a different order than the original, therefore each object uses a different range of vertices. You should find that the total number of vertex lines, face lines etc. should all match up, just that each object is using different numbers.

Comment: I see... but still... original file has 80837 lines of code and exported one only 62736. Also faces in original file have more info: x/x/x x/x/x x/x/x, while in the exported one they look like x/x x/x x/x. Info about normal index is gone.

Comment: As per the wikipedia reference the face info is vertex/texture/normal - dropping the vertex normals might explain dropping 18000 lines. When exporting to obj there is an option to export normals, turning that on could make a difference.